# ServerSelectionTimeoutError errno 11001 getaddrinfo failed python

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, nosql

```
mongodb_uri = "mongodb://[username:password@]XX.XX.XX.XX"

client = MongoClient(mongodb_uri)
db = client['database']
print(db)

collection_taxonomy = db['collection']

doc = collection_taxonomy.find()
pprint.pprint(doc)
for each_doc in doc:
    pprint.pprint(each_doc)
```

I am getting `time out error` as I try to print each document of the collection. However, I do not get time out error when I try to connect to `localhost`.

Tried connecting with `connect=False
client = MongoClient(mongodb_uri,connect=False)`

Still I get time out error while i print each document.
What could be wrong? Appreciate if someone can help me .
I am using Python 3.5 and Pymongo 3.5.1
Thanks,
-Roopa

Answer (score 0):

is "mongodb://[username:password@]XX.XX.XX.XX" the actual value of mongodb_uri or have you substituted that for the value in your actual application?

The "getaddrinfo failed" message indicates that the hostname you put in mongodb_uri is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Removed square brackets([]) after substituting values in actual application.
 "mongodb://username:password@XX.XX.XX.XX"

Works like a charm.!
Thanks a ton.

Roopa

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when i had a restricted rights on the user account which was trying to connect, so please try changing the user access rights or use a different account with higher privileges

user with the below rights failed
readWrite@dbname.colname

user with the below rights worked (note this is the user created for Atlas application)
atlasAdmin@admin

Answer (score 0):

The URI should be like "mongodb://username:password@host", where the host is the hostname or IP.

This happened to me when I was connecting with the name, but the host name changed, so I changed the URI to connect via the machine's IP.